# How can I make sure that a scalardl environment works properly after setting up or modifying the environment?

Tags: scalardl

I have a question about Scalar DL.
How can I make sure that a scalardl environment works properly after setting up or modifying the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a read-only contract if you have one in your applications or you can use Scalar DL Explorer otherwise.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardl-tools/tree/master/explorer